# Error with SSL and TLS on Windows server 2019

Tags: ssl, iis, remote-desktop, windows-server

After I updated the windows server 2019, it is not possible to connect to the server using remote desktop connection. Also the sites which are hosted on https on this server can't be opened and the Chrome browser shows error ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. The remote desktop connection client return error 0x4 and no more information.
When I check the windows event log there are two kinds of errors:

- an error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint mywebsite.com:443. the error status code is contained within the returned data. (Event ID: 15021, Source: HttpEvent)
- A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the TLS server credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic is 0x8009030D. The internal error state is 10001. (Event ID: 36870, Source: Schannel)

---

- I removed the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA and it is created again automatically with default permissions. It didn't solve the problem.
- I can't update the windows, it says "We couldn't connect to update service ..."

Comment: Just checked a bit of your profile and if you don't mind I would make a two suggestions: firstly please accept answers on questions, and secondly, [se] is a large network of Q/A sites, check a few of the other sites! If you don't have a tag for a programming environment for your question then it is likely not on topic at [so].